# Video playlist with percentage bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, local-storage

i'm trying to create video playlist for courses website so i want show to the user how many percentage he finished from his course and every time he opens his course still save in which video he was watching and which minutes !!!!!

Any Help

Answer (score 0):

I just want to understand that: the guy finished a course video and click another course video, it counts 1? I mean It means "You watched that". If this is true, you can count every click to another video. You can save the clicks and video names in a database. And the guy turned back your course site,

1-Control the database video names and counts.

2-If a video name has a number that be 1 or higher, "Yes, he/she watched it before". I can add a percentage point.

But I don't think it can be clearly usable. Because if the guy who watches your course videos want to see all your videos and click them but not watch; it will count "Yes you watched them all".

If you have any video player like Udemy has, you can control anything with that.